# Disconnecting bluetooth make audio out fail when playing media?

Tags: bluetooth, audio, mediaplayer

I use my Nokia Lumia 800 with the bluetooth device BH-111 (see image). It works great and it easily takes both Spotify (streaming music player) and Marathon (running tracker) audio output at the same time.

[image: BH-111 bluetooth device]

After a much needed run (I'm a professional developer) I disconnect bluetooth - but get no media output from the phone. It doesn't matter in which order I disconnect bluetooth (1) shut off BH-111 or (2) turn bluetooth off on the phone. Both actions have the same result - media output from Spotify will not play on phone speaker or phone plug out.

It won't play again until i restart the phone.

Is this a just a coincidence or does it happen to others? **Does disconnecting bluetooth make audio out fail when playing media**?

Comment: Please do not include the make/model as a tag http://meta.windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/20/should-we-encourage-people-to-tag-their-questions-with-their-handset-model-and-n

Comment: I have experienced the same thing with my Lumia 900. (With standard headphones) sometimes when I disconnect them audio won't play at all until I reboot the phone. I would venture a guess this is a bug

Comment: @Joe I think so too, probably should report it to Nokia then.

Comment: I happened a few times on my Samsung focus. I think it is a WP bug

Comment: Does muting the volume (such that it only displays "vibrate") and unmuting it resolve the problem?

Comment: I havn't tried it but I will @TomWijsman. I'll get back to you when I've tried it. Thanx.

Comment: Tried it but it didn't work. Another strange thing is that I cannot change in-call volume when on cord. Sounds like I have to get back to the retailer with the phone?!

Answer (score 1):

Edit: question changed so i also changed my answer.

I've read that more people seem to have this bug. ofcourse it's not meant to stop working if the only way to fix it is rebooting your phone. Maybe the best way to get this fixed is to contact Nokia?

on a side note that is now unrelated to this question my old answer:

When you remove your headphones jack plug from the phone the music will pause.
This is done so you dont get music playing loudly from the speakers when you remove your headphones

Pressing the play button should continue playing the music

Comment: Thanx, but I need to restart the phone to get it playing again. I updated my question accordingly.

Comment: changed answer a bit... but just seems to be a bug we can't really help you with.